# List and String in list/map

Tags: java, list, dictionary

I stuck we probably a pretty simple question. I want a method like this. I want it to both return a list with user objects but also a String or some other datatype.

Is this possible?
Should I use `Map`, `List` or some other solution?

```
public RETURNTYPE getInformations(){
    ArrayList<User> users = new ArrayList<>();
    String myMessage;
    
    return ??
}
```

Comment: The question is too vague. However, *generally speaking* when you want to return 2 items you have a design flaw. Your method `getInformations ()` is in plural therefor I expect it to return a list of `Information`, just from the initial look.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a class which will hold the propertys you want to return and return an instance of the named class. Its safe and helps if you have to rework your code.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1. create a class to hold your list + string, something like (using [lombok](https://projectlombok.org/)):

```
@Data(staticConstructor="of")
class Information {
    private final List<User> theList;
    private final String theString;
}
```

Step 2. use this custom class:

```
public Information getInformation(){
    List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();
    String myMessage = "someMessage";
    return Information.of(users, myMessage);
}
```

Comment: Yeah, Have thought of this option. Just thought there could be another way than creating a class

Comment: following up on that. So you should never hesitate to create classes. Maybe a stupid question, but is it never overkill?

Comment: Again IMHO, it can be (for example a class with one field) but you need to think things like this: if someone read the code later, does it make sense. In your question example, it makes sense to have some `Information` class (and as stated in comments to name the method `getInformation` [no s]).